# @EventListener spring boot fails to compile

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, pom.xml

Wrote my first Spring Boot app that count number of refreshes. I print to port 8080 "Hello World" + Counter.

Counter should increase at each user refresh and show on live the number of refreshes after the "Hello World" string.

For this goal I am using the @RestController and @EventListener interfaces.

When building my app, it fails on @EventListener import and interface call:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:2.3.2:compile (default-compile) on project backend: Compilation failure: Compilation failure: 
[ERROR] /home/project/backend/src/main/java/com/iz/backend/myController.java:[9,58] error: cannot find symbol
[ERROR]  package org.springframework.cloud.context.config.annotation
[ERROR] /home/project/backend/src/main/java/com/iz/backend/myController.java:[57,5] error: incompatible types: EventListener cannot be converted to Annotation
```

Class:

```
package com.iz.backend;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.cloud.context.config.annotation.RefreshScope;
import org.springframework.cloud.context.config.annotation.EventListener;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Files; 
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.nio.file.Path;

@RefreshScope
@RestController //interface
public class myController {

    static int counter = -1;

    @RequestMapping("/")
    public String helloWorld() {

        try
        {
            return "Hello World " + counter;
        } 
        catch (IOException e) 
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return "Failed to execute";
    }
    
    @EventListener
    public void handleContextRefreshEvent(ContextRefreshedEvent event) {
        counter += 1;
    }
}
```

pom.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.4.1</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>
<groupId>com.iz</groupId>
<artifactId>backend</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>backend</name>
<description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

<properties>
    <java.version>11</java.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-source-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.4</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-aop</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0</version>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

MAVEN 3.6.3, JAVA 11

Comment: You have two imports for `EventListener`. Remove one (probably `java.util.EventListener`).

Comment: I added this line to here by mistake. Edited now. In my actual code     java.util.EventListener    doesn't exist.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to do the following:

1. Remove the try catch block (Exception 'java.io.IOException' is never thrown in the corresponding try block)
2. Optimize the imports (you have duplicate/ambigous imports)
3. Use something like an AtomicInteger as counter